# jUnit same exception in different cases

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm writing a jUnit test for a constructor that parses a String and then check numerous things. When there's wrong data, for every thing, some IllegalArgumentException with different message is thrown.
So I would like to write tests for it, but how can i recognize what error was thrown?
This is how can I do it:

```
@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testRodneCisloRok(){
    new RodneCislo("891415",dopocitej("891415"));
}
```

and this is how I would like to be, but I don't know if it is possible to write it somehow:

```
@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class("error1"))
public void testRodneCisloRok(){
    new RodneCislo("891415",dopocitej("891415"));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to do it the old fashioned way:

```
@Test
public void testRodneCisloRok() {
    try {
       new RodneCislo("891415",dopocitej("891415"));
       fail("expected an exception");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
       assertEquals("error1", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The `@Test(expected=...)` syntax is a handy convenience, but it's too simple in many cases.

If it is important to distinguish between exception conditions, you might want to consider developing a class hierarchy of exceptions, that can be caught specifically. In this case, a subclass of `IllegalArgumentException` might be a good idea. It's arguably better design, and your test can catch that specific exception type.

Answer (score 34):

If you have **JUnit 4.7** or above you can use this (elegant) way:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testRodneCisloRok(){
    exception.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    exception.expectMessage("error1");
    new RodneCislo("891415",dopocitej("891415"));
}
```