# JUnit Testing Exceptions

Tags: java, junit

I'm really new to java.

I'm running some JUnit tests on a constructor. The constructor is such that if it is given a null or an empty string for one of its parameters, it's supposed to throw an exception.

When I test this constructor in JUnit with a null or an empty string parameter, I get a red bar, even though I'm almost 100% sure that the constructor method does indeed throw an exception when such parameters are passed in to it.

Shouldn't there be a green bar in JUnit if the method throws an exception the way it is supposed to? Or is it that when you are supposed to get a red bar when the exception throwing works the way it is supposed to?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
```

Tells Junit that exception is the expected result so test will be passed (marked as green) when exception is thrown.

For

```
@Test
```

Junit will consider test as failed if exception is thrown, **provided it's an unchecked exception**. If the exception is checked it won't compile and you will need to use other methods.
This [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html#juniteclipse_test) might help.

Comment: But how to pass the custom message via this solution? I mean the business logic is: `throw IOException("username can't be null")`. I know about `org.junit.rules.ExpectedException`, but I do not want to create an instance and using `.expect(` and `.expectMessage(`

Answer (score 47):

are you sure you told it to expect the exception?

for newer junit (>= 4.7), you can use something like (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489801/junit-test-analysing-expected-exceptions))

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testRodneCisloRok(){
    exception.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    exception.expectMessage("error1");
    new RodneCislo("891415",dopocitej("891415"));
}
```

and for older junit, this:

```
@Test(expected = ArithmeticException.class)  
public void divisionWithException() {  
  int i = 1/0;
}
```

Comment: If the test class throws an exception, you can simply throw the exception and test where you have written the Junit test cases. with using @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)

Answer (score 6):

If your constructor is similar to this one:

```
public Example(String example) {
    if (example == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    //do fun things with valid example here
}
```

Then, when you run this JUnit test you will get a green bar:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void constructorShouldThrowNullPointerException() {
    Example example = new Example(null);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

An adventage of use ExpectedException Rule (version 4.7) is that you can test exception message and not only the expected exception.

And using Matchers, you can test the part of message you are interested:

```
exception.expectMessage(containsString("income: -1000.0"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Though `@Test(expected = MyException.class)` and the [ExpectedException rule](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) are very good choices, there are some instances where the JUnit3-style exception catching is still the best way to go:

```
@Test public void yourTest() {
  try {
    systemUnderTest.doStuff();
    fail("MyException expected.");
  } catch (MyException expected) {

    // Though the ExpectedException rule lets you write matchers about
    // exceptions, it is sometimes useful to inspect the object directly.

    assertEquals(1301, expected.getMyErrorCode());
  }

  // In both @Test(expected=...) and ExpectedException code, the
  // exception-throwing line will be the last executed line, because Java will
  // still traverse the call stack until it reaches a try block--which will be
  // inside the JUnit framework in those cases. The only way to prevent this
  // behavior is to use your own try block.

  // This is especially useful to test the state of the system after the
  // exception is caught.

  assertTrue(systemUnderTest.isInErrorState());
}
```

Another library that claims to help here is [catch-exception](https://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/); however, as of May 2014, the project appears to be in maintenance mode (obsoleted by Java 8), and much like Mockito catch-exception can only manipulate non-`final` methods.