# How to assert Userdefined Exceptions in JUNIT4.7

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, junit4

I'm using JUNIT 4.7 using maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have my method for uploading a file and I'm using my own userdefined exceptions as below

```
public void uploadFile(String fileName) {
    File file  = null;

    try {
        file = new File(DIR + "/" + fileName);

        // If the file size exceeds 10 MB raise an exception
        if ((file.length() / MB) > 10)
            throw new FileSizeExceedLimitException("File size should not exceed 10 MB");

        else {
            System.out.println("File Uploaded Successfully");
        }
    } catch (FileSizeExceedLimitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And my User defined exceptions looks like below

```
public class FileSizeExceedLimitException extends Exception{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FileSizeExceedLimitException(String s){
        super(s);
    }
}
```

And my Test cases are looks like below

Method 1 :

```
DocxOperations operations = null;

@Rule
public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Before
public void before() {
    operations = new DocxOperations();
}

@Test
public void testUploadFileSize() {
    exception.expect(FileSizeExceedLimitException.class);
    operations.uploadFile("Bigdata.docx");
}
```

Method 2 :

```
@Test(expected = FileFormatException.class)
public void testUploadFile() {
    operations.uploadFile("01 Big Data Hadoop Intro V 2.0.docx");
}
```

Method 3 :

```
@Test(expected = FileFormatException.class)
public void testUploadFile() throws FileFormatException{
    operations.uploadFile("01 Big Data Hadoop Intro V 2.0.docx");
}
```

In all the above methods i'm unable to pass the test cases,and i have seen these solutions but they are not useful for me

[Assert Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156503/how-do-you-assert-that-a-certain-exception-is-thrown-in-junit-4-tests), [Testing Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904380/junit-4-12-issue-testing-exception)

> In my main code i.e in `uploadFile` method i have to use only `try`, `catch`
>   not `throws`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you aren't throwing the exception beyond your method call:

Here is the simplifed code with just the throw and catch to see it more clearly

```
try {
   ...

        throw new FileSizeExceedLimitException("File size should not exceed 10 MB");
    ...

  } catch (FileSizeExceedLimitException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You are catching and swallowing the exception.  Remove the try-catch and make your method `throws FileSizeExceedLimitException`  and the test should work

Comment: thanks for answering, but In my main code i.e in `uploadFile` method i have to use only `try`, `catch` not `throws`